# Write a list from "munsell"

Tags: r

I have never used R before, and I am after the hex codes from `library("munsell")`. I have skimmed through the [notes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/munsell/), but have resorted to the following tedious method:

```
mnsl(seq_mnsl("2.5R 1/2", "2.5R 9/2", 9))
mnsl(seq_mnsl("2.5R 1/4", "2.5R 8/4", 8))
mnsl(seq_mnsl("2.5R 1/6", "2.5R 8/6", 8))
mnsl(seq_mnsl("2.5R 2/8", "2.5R 7/8", 6))
mnsl(seq_mnsl("2.5R 3/10", "2.5R 7/10", 5))
mnsl(seq_mnsl("2.5R 4/12", "2.5R 6/12", 3))
mnsl(seq_mnsl("2.5R 4/14", "2.5R 6/14", 3))
mnsl("2.5R 5/16")
```

this is clearly not a good way to get the codes. Please could someone help me to export a full list for all 40 hues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package has an internal object called `munsell.map` that is used for the conversions. It should contain what you are looking for. You can access it with:

```
munsell:::munsell.map
```

To export the conversion table as a CSV:

```
write.csv(munsell:::munsell.map, "munsell_map.csv")
```

Or view it in the Viewer:

```
View(munsell:::munsell.map)
```

Comment: slight problem, it wont let me see the top of the list. I have tried exporting with `lapply(mylist, write.table(munsell:::munsell.map, 'R.csv'  , append= T, sep=',' ))` , but throws up error

Comment: I added commands for exporting as CSV or viewing the contents.